# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 x64 can't update maven indexs

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, indexing

**i have download the index files from**

> repo1.maven.org/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
>   repo1.maven.org/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz

**than use httpServer ,and edit hosts file in windows10,

so that idea can download maven index files from localhost success,

but ,gzip is fail...**

```
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerIndexerException: 
              java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

> [See    Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAenF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem is happend because the file
       `nexus-maven-repository-index.gz` is not good,
        so download the file from this URL is no problem

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
```

[image: SuccessPicture]